# how to put "a string",a number,"a string",another number in a string arra

Tags: c++, string, syntax-error

I have question about putting data below in a string array , I mean that is it possible to do as bellow:

```
for(int i{};i<num;i++)
    string[i]={"The degree of",i,"'th vertice is",degree[i]}
```

I have tried that and I know its not practical in c++ but is there any other way to do so, my goal is to return a string that number of each degree is saved in by a function called degree,as what I have mentioned (for example "The degree of 4'th vertice is 2") .
so is there possible to do so?
I want to call the function as below:

```
std::cout<<degree();
```

thanks for your attention.

Comment: `string[i] = "The degree of " + std::to_string(i) + "'th vertice is " + std::to_string(degree[i]);`

Comment: thanks for your answer but is there possible to save text below in string and not string array:
(The degree of 4'th vertice is 2 (new line)
The degree of 5'th vertice is 3  (new line)
The degree of 6'th vertice is 0  (new line)
The degree of 7'th vertice is 6)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You better ask for what you want to do and not for something different ;) You cant print a string array like this `std::cout<<degree();` (unless you provide corresponding overload), but of course you can concatenate strings and ints

Comment: sorry for not expressing my mean correctly I want to store all vertice degrees in one string so when I call the function like this:   std::cout<<degree();  show all degrees as the format I mentioned above and not just one of node's degree because the function degree does not have any parameter so I want to show the degrees of all nodes, and that I have to save them in just one string and not in array of string.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can put everything in a single string and put a newline (`'\n'`) between each logical line. Just combine the code snippets given above:

```
std::string degrees()
{
    std::string   lines;

    for(int i{};i<num;i++)
        lines += "The degree of " + std::to_string(i) +
                 "'th vertice is " + std::to_string(degree[i]) + '\n';

   return lines;
}
```

Comment: @A.salehy Then mark it as [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)! This the right way to say thank you in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this as well (edited to remove argument passing to degrees fnc, as OP doesn't want that):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int> degree = { 1,5,4,8,2,12,4,30,45,22 };

std::string degrees()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < degree.size(); ++i)
        oss << (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") << "The degree of " << i + 1 << "'th vertice is " << degree[i];

    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << degrees() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

[image]

Comment: Suggesting a small improvement: Use `std::ostringstream` if you don't need input operations.

Comment: thanks for answer but I have to use function "degree" without any parameter.

Comment: @A.salehy Edited my answer